# Spatiality of products of locally compact locales

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, locales

In Johnstone´s Sketches of an Elephant Volume 2, page 716,

lemma 4.1.8 states that for spatial locales $X$ and $Y$ with $X$ locally compact then the locale product $X\times Y$ is spatial.

Is this lemma still valid for a family of locally compact spatial locales, that is, if $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ is a family of locally compact spatial locales is the locale $\prod_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ spatial?

Or anyone knows a modification for a countable family of locally compact spatial locales?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please change the title to something more descriptive, e.g., "Spatiality of products of locally compact locales" or something similar.

Comment: Also could you please formulate the statement that you have in mind? Do you mean localic coproduct or product or what?

Comment: I mean what do you intend to do with that family? Take its coproduct and multiply by $Y$? Or take its product and multiply by $Y$? Or multiply each of the $X_\alpha$ by $Y$ and then take coproduct of these products? Or multiply and then take product? You ask about validity of a statement but I cannot figure out what this statement is, sorry.

Comment: It seem rather clear to me that the question is about wether an infinite product of spatial and locally compact locales is spatial. Product mean product in the category of locales (hence coproduct in the category of frame).

Comment: I don't know the answer in general, I suspect it is no. Though you might be interestedi in knowing that if your locales are countably presented (like separable metric spaces) and the product is countable then the answer is yes.

Comment: @SimonHenry Oh I see, thanks, you have any information of where I can find that result?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It mean that the product is in the category of locales, that is, the coproduct in the category of frames

Comment: I see now, thanks. @SimonHenry The present version did not occur to me. I was confused because i thought the question is about a *generalization* of the cited lemma, while in fact it turns out not to be the case

Comment: @AngelZaldívar : the results about countably presented locales being spatial can be found in S.Valentini "Every countably presented formal topology is spatial, classically " https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1146620155

A product of countably generated locale is again countably generated and it should be possible to show that separable metric spaces are countably generated locales, though I don't know a references for that.

Comment: I think there is also a version of the result for toposes which is actually older than Valentini's work, but I haven't been able to find it.